# What is the differential on the space of trajectories and why does it anti-commute with the regular differential on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics

From [Classical Field Theory by Deligne and Freed](https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/79_ClassicalFieldTheory.pdf), page 143 (page 6 in this pdf)  $x$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $X$ which is Euclidean space with standard inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$.  We have Lagrangian density

$$L = \frac{m}{2} |\dot{x}|^2 dt$$

If we deform x we have

$$\delta L = m\langle \dot{x}, \delta \dot{x}\rangle dt = -m\langle \ddot{x},\delta x\rangle dt -d\{m\langle \dot{x}, \delta x\rangle \}$$

It says $\delta$ is the differential on the space of trajectories.  What does that mean?  What are some resources to get a more basic understanding of what is going on with this manipulation?

Comment: Anticommuting does not make the equation correct. I believe the sign on the last term is incorrect.

Comment: @TedShifrin there’s a comment on the bottom of page 144(page 7 in the pdf) explaining the convention.  Is it still in error with this convention?

Comment: You should read carefully all the text and the footnote. Apparently they are interpreting $\langle v,\delta x\rangle$ as the contraction of the vector-valued $1$-form $\delta x$ with the vector $v$, rather than as an inner product of tangent vectors. Although the spatial and time partial derivatives, they are noting that $d\delta = -\delta d$ because $dt\wedge dx = -dx\wedge dt$ …

Comment: Oops. Insert “commute” after “partial derivatives.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to take the derivative of $L$ as a function defined on the infinite dimensional space of (sufficiently differentiable) paths in $X$:
$\{x:\mathrm R\to X\}$.

This is done by considering a "nearby" path $x+\varepsilon y$ where $y:\mathbb R\to X$ and $\varepsilon \in \mathbb R$ is sent to zero.
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac1\varepsilon(L(x+\varepsilon y) - L(x))
&= \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac1\varepsilon \frac m2 \left[\langle \dot x+\varepsilon \dot y, \dot x+\varepsilon \dot y \rangle - \langle \dot x, \dot x \rangle \right]~dt \\
&= \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} m\left[ \langle\dot x, \dot y\rangle  + \frac{\varepsilon}2\langle \dot y, \dot y\rangle\right] \\
&= m\langle \dot x, \dot y\rangle
\end{align*}
$$
This will give you the directional derivative of $L$ in the direction $y$, $\mathrm d L(y)$.
If we want a "full gradient" of $L$ then we want to rewrite it as an inner product with $y$.
Integrate by parts (without the integral) to get
$$
\mathrm dL(y) = m\left(\frac{d}{dt} \langle \dot x, y\rangle - \langle \ddot x, y\rangle\right) ~dt
$$
If you assume $y$ has compact support, then the boundary term disappears in the integral $\int L~dt$. In that case we see that $\mathrm d L = -m \ddot x$.
This differential is also denoted $\delta L$ and is called the variation of $L$ in $x$.

Maybe you can take a look at [calculus of variations (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations)

Comment: This makes sense but I think the biggest thing that I’m having trouble with is understanding the notion of “tangent space” to the space of trajectories.  If, for instance, X was an arbitrary smooth manifold, what would $x + \varepsilon y$ even mean?  How do we put a smooth structure on the soace of trajectories?

Comment: yes I'm exploiting the fact that you map to a Euclidean space $X$. In a more general manifold, you will need a way to describe the tangent space before you can say anything more in detail. But in theory, you can still take derivatives on a smooth manifold.

Comment: That’s not what’s tripping me up.  I’m familiar with how derivatives on smooth finite dimensional manifolds work.  What we’re dealing with here, the infinite dimensional space of trajectories, feels like another beast entirely.  How to we even define the smooth structure on it?

For a finite dimensional manifolds, we define the tangent space in a number of ways, equivalence class of smooth curves, space of derivations, but they each require some notion of smoothness on the space first.  What we’re trying to formalize is the tangent space to the space of trajectories.

Comment: I found a satisfying discussion of the ideas [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65926/the-tangent-bundle-to-an-infinite-dimensional-manifold?newreg=c00dc744c6bf4b359a8dffa8899b3d34)